# python use ProcessPoolExecutor easiliy?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

First I use `ProcessPoolExecutor` like this:

```
def s(i):
    time.sleep(1)
    return i

futs = []
with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
    for i in range(WORKER_CNT):
        print executor.submit(s, i,).result()
```

but then I find this is not parallel, then I change to this:

```
def s(i):
    time.sleep(1)
    return i

futs = []
with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
    for i in range(WORKER_CNT):
        futs.append(executor.submit(s, i,))

for f in futs:
    print f.result()
```

Then I begin to worry about the `WORKER_CNT` can be too big, and I need to wait to much time to see the last result, so I change to this:

```
def s(i):
    time.sleep(1)
    return i

futs = []
with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
    for i in range(WORKER_CNT):
        futs.append(executor.submit(s, i,))
        if len(futs) == 10:
            for f in futs:
                print f.result()
            futs = []
```

this time, I can process `10` each time, **I want to know can I do this easier?**

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.map) *method* of the `Executor` class:

```
def s(i):
    time.sleep(1)
    return i

with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
    results = executor.map(s, range(WORKER_CNT))
```

It has some other options to control how the execution is performed.

Note that `results` is **not** a list. It's an *iterator* which receives values as they are computed. So the following code:

```
with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
    for result in executor.map(s, range(WORKER_CNT)):
        print(result)
```

will only keep in memory one result at a time, since they are consumed in a fraction of a second and take much more time to produce.